# When I hover over my div I don't want it effecting all the divs with the same class?

Tags: jquery

when I hover over my div the pop up fades in like it should but it affects all the other divs with the same class as well. I just want it to effect the div that's being hovered on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".project").hover(function() {
        $('.caption').fadeToggle(1000);              
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply provide a context:

```
$(".project").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeToggle(1000);              
});
```

With this approach, jQuery will look at the current `.project` element and look within that element for descendant elements with the class of `caption`; rather than looking at the whole document.

Comment: Thank you David, very much appreciated. That worked like a charm : )

Comment: Apparently I can't accept your answer for another 7 minutes lol : )